# viewport value in accordance to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, viewport

I don't know if this is possible. Check out this non-functional website:

http://imageworkz.asia/sixsensestester/

When viewed in a big screen, it looks as if the container floats in the center of the screen but when viewed with a smaller screen, let us say, by a 1366x768 monitor, it zooms and shows as if the site is zoomed. I do know that screen resolution matters, so is it possible to make the website's zoom adjust accordingly to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries). It uses CSS to detect the viewport size and set style rules accordingly. There are a lot of tutorials about them so learning them should be easy to do.